# How is foldLeft evaluated in (0 /: (1 to 6))(_+_)?

Tags: scala

I was exploring the Scala foldLeft and its operator `/:`. And I came across an article [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/1562).

Here the `/:` is used to evaluate the sum of 1 to 6 as

```
(0 /: (1 to 6))(_+_)
```

The syntax of foldLeft that I am aware of is like `Range./:(Initial Value){(z, i) => some anonymous function definition}`

How is `(0 /: (1 to 6))(_+_)` evaluated and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators ending in `:` are right associative. this means it's the same as explicitly using dot notation `(1 to 6)./:(0)(_+_)`

It is the same reason `1 :: 2 :: Nil` doesn't have to be `1 :: (2 :: Nil)`

Comment: How is 0 /: (1 to 6) section evaluated? I thought left side of /: should be a collection. But here it is an integer. Strange.

Comment: If possible could you please explain more verbose. Sorry, if this seems too tedious. I have just started learning scala, and I just want to have my foundations correct.

Comment: yeah sure no problem. So all symbolic method names that end in a `:` means that they "associate to the right" which means it's like flipped dot-notation. so it'd be `<method> +: <object>` for example.

The easiest example is probably the cons operator of lists `::`. this is just prepend on a linked list really not that if we do `1 :: Nil` the List is actually on the right hand side because our operator ends in `:`. This makes sense in this case because we're *PRE*pending.

Comment: so now for `(0 /: (1 to 6))(_+_)`. let's look at the fold left signature which is `B => ((A,B) => B) => B` for something foldable with `A`s in it. so looking at the part `(0 /: (1 to 6))` you have the foldable thing on the right because `/:` associates to the right and then we have our initial element on the left. So this expression would evaluate to `(A,B) => B => B` (in scala we have to do partial application manually though). With `(_+_)` we pass in the `(A,B) => B` part in and this all will resolve to a `B` (Also note that in our example both `A` and `B` are `Int`)

Comment: here you have a little fiddle with an example https://scalafiddle.io/sf/JxLd6Bf/1

Comment: got it now. thanks. This right associativity was confusing. Now it is clear.

Comment: @Dominic: there is some valuable information in the comments here. Could you copy them to the answer? We tend to say that comments are temporary here, so if they contain anything of value, they are best in a post.