# What is the definition of this function in plain english?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand this spelling correction module [here](http://theyougen.blogspot.com/2009/12/peter-norvigs-spelling-corrector-in.html). I am stuck with the following function definition:

```
def correct(word : String) = ((-1, word) /: candidates(word))(
  (max, word) => if(dict(word) > max._1) (dict(word), word) else max)._2
```

I understand the function prototype as `def correct(word : String)` accepting a `String`, but the right hand side expression is very confusing given that I am a beginner in Scala.

What's happening in the right hand side, especially with that `foldLeft` operator `/:`? Also, what is the return type of this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like maximisation for a given `word` over a list of `candidates` using the function `dict: String => Int`. For each word in the `candidates` list, compute it's score using `dict` if it it's score is bigger than the previously retained element, keep it instead.

The return type should be `String` if I did my brain-compilation right.

another way to write the start would be

```
candidates.foldLeft((-1, word))(...)
```

Also I actually just answered a question on the `foldLeft` vs `/:` topic 
[How is foldLeft evaluated in (0 /: (1 to 6))(_+_)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296221/how-is-foldleft-evaluated-in-0-1-to-6/53296264#53296264)

Edit:
e.g. you have the `word` "citi" and candidates `city, citizen, exciting` and your `dict` could be the levenshtein function.

Comment: So in (-1, word), -1 is for the max calculation right? and the word is the current word in the candidates list?

Comment: so yeah it's a bit unfortunate. the `word` in `((-1, word) /: candidates(word))` refers to the parameter. in the lambda it's the current entry in the `candidates` list. it's an issue of shadowing names.  I assume that `-1` was chosen because `dict` return a non-negative integer so the first actual call to `dict` will replace the initial somewhat senseless element.